# C# - Dynamically creating MenuStrip

Tags: c#, menustrip, toolstripitem

I'm creating a web browser with tabs. To enter the URL, I'm trying to set a MenuStrip with its  `ToolStripMenuItem` as a Textbox. I'm creating all the controls dynamically and I have 2 questions.

1). How can I insert a Textbox as the `ToolStripMenuItem` from the code?

(for this screenshot only I added the MenuStrip at design time)

[image]

2). How can I change its width?

Thank you all.

Comment: Easy to do in code by adding a ToolStripTextBox to the menu item's DropDownItems collection.  Not very good UI though, it isn't obvious that it is text box until the user selects it.  And there's no good way to signal "I'm done typing!"

Comment: @HansPassant : I agree. It doesn't look like a Textbox at all! I use `Focus()` method to focus the cursor into the Textbox whenever a new tab is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ToolStripTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriptextbox.aspx)

```
  toolStripTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox();
  toolStripTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
  toolStrip1.Items.Add(toolStripTextBox1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the control:

```
var textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripTextBox();
```

Set up some properties:

```
textBox.Name = "someName";
textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 25); // width, height
```

Add it to the `ToolStrip`:

```
toolStrip.Items.Add(textBox);
```